# "connect to address x.x.x.x port nnnnn Connection refused"

Tags: networking, server, ssh

When I ssh ( Openssh (7.2p2 ) to (Ubuntu 16.04) server from the (Ubuntu 18.04) workstation for the first time I get the following message "connect to address x.x.x.x port nnnnn Connection refused" (port 22 is not being used ) and ufw has been set to allow the port number being used.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `sshd.service` is running:

```
$ systemctl status sshd
```

If it is not running, run it:

```
$ sudo systemctl start sshd
```

`Connection refused` could be because of the service is not running, the port is wrong or firewall could block it.

You could allow ssh by the next command:

```
$ sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Check if your service is actually running on specified port (replace 22 to your own specified port):

```
$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep "22 "
cupsd       791            root    7u  IPv4  27822      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
sshd      10927            root    3u  IPv4 135947      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      10927            root    4u  IPv6 135949      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Check if you could connect to localhost first:

```
$ ssh user@localhost -p 22
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips which will become useful later on. I had to purge the installation using apt-get purge openssh-server  and then re-install. Purging seemed to work better than re-installing although I think your comments would have helped had I known about them at the time. I seem to be getting another problem and that of the system appearing to login Ok but defaults to the client installation. Any ideas? Thanks again..